# Pushing a new VC into the navigationController seems to have no effect

Tags: ios

This problem sounds quite basic but I don’t understand what I am overlooking.

I am trying to push a new view controller into a navigation controller, however the topViewController remains unaffected.

```
#import "TNPViewController.h"
@interface TNCViewController : UIViewController <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>

@implementation TNCViewController

-(void)userDidSelectNewsNotification:(NSNotification*)note

{

    TNPViewController *nextViewController = [[TNPViewController alloc] init];

    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];

    UIViewController *test = [[self navigationController] topViewController];

}
```

The test shows an instance of TNCViewController instead of TNPViewController. How is this possible?

**UPDATE**

Thanks for everyone's participation.  The method name indicating notifications is a red herring. I found the problem, as Stuart had mentioned previously but deleted later on. (As I have high reputation score, I still can see his deleted post).

My initial unit test was this:

```
-(void)testSelectingNewsPushesNewViewController
{
    [viewController userDidSelectNewsNotification:nil];
    UIViewController *currentTopVC = navController.topViewController;
    XCTAssertFalse([currentTopVC isEqual:viewController], @"New viewcontroller should be pushed onto the stack.");
    XCTAssertTrue([currentTopVC isKindOfClass:[TNPViewController class]], @"New vc should be a TNPViewController");
}
```

And it failed. Then I set a breakpoint and tried the `test` instance above and it still was showing the wrong topviewcontroller.

At least the unit test works if I change

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];
```

to

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:nextViewController animated:NO];
```

A better solution is to use an ANIMATED constant for unit tests to disable the animations.

Comment: Pushing controller tooks some time. It is not finished when you are trying to read top controller

Comment: Wouldn't it be wiser to simply add the next view controller on the storyboard and pass it through segues? Then change the content accordingly? Instead of initializing every time a new TNPViewController...

Comment: check this `[self navigationController].title=@"Some Title";` If this doesnt work it should prove that your UI has actually some other navigation VC which is not equal to `[self navigationController]`

Comment: Can you show the code that registers to receive the notifications for your `userDidSelectNewsNotification:` method? I suspect there could be issue related to threading.

Comment: @oxigen I originally thought so too, but testing shows that this is not the case. Yes, the transition is deferred (has been for animated transitions since iOS 7), but `topViewController` is set to the new view controller immediately after the call to `pushViewController:animated:`.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really answer your question about why your navigationController is not pushing your VC. But it is a suggestion about another possible approach.

You could instead add a new VC on the Storyboard and simply activate the segue when the `userDidSelectNewsNotification` method is activated. Then change the information accordingly to the event in the VC, specially since you are initializing it every time anyway.

Comment: While I agree that storyboards can be a more convenient way to manage an app's UI, I think you misunderstand how they work. View controllers in storyboards are _not_ reused; a new one is initialized each time a storyboard segue is performed, just like in @Houman's programmatic approach. In fact, this can be a reason _not_ to use storyboards, because in code you could store and reuse difficult-to-load view controllers rather than instantiating a new one every time from a storyboard.

Comment: @Stuart Thanks for that, yes I must've misunderstood their inner workings. Depends on his application i guess. But it still is easier to use and understand IMHO. I see now the benefit of the programmatic approach though. If he is going to initialize it everytime anyway segues is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

This is something of a stab in the dark, but the issue is hard to diagnose without more information.

I see you're trying to push the new view controller in response to a notification. Are you sure this notification is being handled on the main thread? UI methods such as pushing new view controllers will fail (or at least behave unpredictably) when not performed on the main thread. This may also go some way to explaining the odd behaviour of `topViewController` returning an unexpected view controller instance.*

Ideally, you should guarantee these notifications are posted on the main thread, so they will be received on that same thread. If you cannot guarantee this (for example if you're not responsible for posting the notifications elsewhere in your code), then you should dispatch any UI-related code to the main thread:

```
- (void)userDidSelectNewsNotification:(NSNotification *)note
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        TNPViewController *nextViewController = [[TNPViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TNPViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];
    });
}
```

Also, it appears you are not initialising `TNPViewController` using the designated initialiser (unless in your subclass you are overriding `init` and calling through to `initWithNibName:bundle:` from there?). I wouldn't expect this to cause the transition to fail entirely, but may result in your view controller not being properly initialised.

In general, you might be better creating your view controllers in a storyboard and using segues to perform your navigation transitions, as @Joze suggests in his answer. You can still initiate these storyboard segues in code (e.g. in response to your notification) with `performSegueWithIdentifier:`, but again, be sure to do so on the main thread. See [Using View Controllers in Your App](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH6-SW1) for more details on this approach.

---

**I originally wrote an answer trying to explain the unexpected `topViewController` value as being a result of deferred animated transitions. While it is true that animated transitions are deferred, this does not prevent `topViewController` from being set to the new view controller immediately.*